# Issue with function Overloading in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions

I am trying to declare two  suspend methods with list of String and PublishRequest Object as parameter. But the IDE is giving error with this.
The error is either make one of the function internal or remove suspend. But i want to use coroutines inside both of them.

```
    override suspend fun publish(publishRequests: List<PublishRequest>) {
       ///code

    }


    suspend fun publish(events: List<String>) {
     ///code

    }
```

The PublishRequest Data class is internal. The issues is only coming when we add  the **publish(events: List)** method. The code is working fine the **publish(publishRequests: List)**

Can you explain why it is happening ?

Comment: This is probably due to the fact that PublicRequest is internal and your override is public. You can't expose an internal type in a public function. Just a guess. In any case the code you posted is not enough to answer your question.

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes publish request is internal. Is there any alternate to do this ? .

Comment: Make the function internal or the type public (first one preferred because of encapsulation).

Comment: @m0skit0 , the function is working properly when we only have method  override suspend fun publish(publishRequests: List<PublishRequest>) {
       ///code

    }...   The issue is coming only when we try to add new method

Comment: Like I said, impossible to guess with just that code. Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are facing is related to [type erasure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-erasure).

The types `List<PublishRequest>` and `List<String>` are erased to `List<*>`, as consequence, you would have a JVM signature clash.

To solve your problem you have two different solutions.

1. Change their names and avoid a signature clash:

```kotlin
    suspend fun publishRequests(publishRequests: List<PublishRequest>) {}
    suspend fun publishEvents(events: List<String>) {}
```

2. Use a single function with a `reified` type and handle the different type classes inside that function:

```kotlin
suspend inline fun <reified T> publish(objects: List<T>) {
    when {
        PublishRequest::class.java.isAssignableFrom(T::class.java) -> // it's a list of PublishRequest
        T::class == String::class -> // it's a list of String
    }       
}
```

Comment: Hi @giorgio-antonioli, We were using JvmName annotation to mitigate this concern but that doesn't work with defining methods in interfaces. Can you tell me how can i use this in interfaces

Comment: @Naman_Jain you can't use `@JvmName` in an interface to change the name of a function. You can still use `publish(object: List<T>, klass: Class<T>)` in an interface to check the type.